# jquery slice script with window width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script JS:

```
function thoat() {
    var sples = $(window).width();
    if (sples >= 320 && sples <= 480) {$('.projects').slice(0, 9).css('margin', '10px');
    } else {$('.projects').slice(3, 6).css('margin', '10px');
    }
}thoat();
```

Its when screen size btw 320 and 480 then select all elements if not select the three from bottom.
Its looks like work great but i try on a responsive screen test size with 320px and its not select all element not understand why? On 320px what write there not work

responsive test site where not work with 320px : [screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//jsfiddle.net/ndyVv/5/embedded/result/&w=320&h=480&a=33)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndyVv/5/)

Whats the problem? with script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine actually. The only problem is that you run your function just on `DOM.ready()`, but when you change the resolution on screenfly it does not cause the page reload, so `DOM.ready()` event is not fired, but `$(window).resize()` is. So you can add followingl line to your code

```
$(window).on('resize', thoat);
```

and it works!

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndyVv/13/)

[Screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//jsfiddle.net/ndyVv/13/embedded/result/&w=320&h=240&a=32)
Just resize the screen to some mobile device and you'll see the result.

**UPD** It doesn't work at 320px cause of scrollbar, it's width is like 17px, and `.width()` method returns `window` width without scroll bar witdh, so , in your case it's out of range.

Comment: its ok but on 320px not select all elements? why? on 320 and 480 need select all but why not do not understand?

Comment: this script work about a month not know now why not work at 320px then how i can make its work on 320px ? and thanks u very useful?

Comment: @testers you can try to use native js `window.outerWidth` and it should help, or add 17px to your range up to you :)